# Migrate Data & Applications Windows 2012 to Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, migration

We recently upgraded our web server from Windows 2003 to Windows 2012. Since all the applications needed to be upgraded we didn't use much in the way of migration tools except the a database migration tool. Files and source code were migrated from local backups. But ... it turns out we are unhappy with our service provider. So we need to migrate from one server to another both of which are windows 2012. What is the nest way to do this? Are there any automated tools that will transfer both files, applications users, settings, etc? I am aware of some specific tools to transfer roles and features as well as files, but is there anything that will transfer everything including as email programs, ssl certs, database servers, etc? I though about images, but the VM platform is different, one being Citrix Xen server, the other OnApp Xen Server. We feel the ONApp Xen Server is misconfigured so we don't want to take our problems with us

Comment: I'd look into using Windows Server Backup to capture a full image of the server. The backup should be virtualization platform agnostic. As long as the destination host can give you a basic Windows Server 2012 VM then you ought to be able to restore the backup to the new VM. The only caveat is that you may want/need to uninstall any guest tools/services that are specific to the virtualization platform before capturing the backup, if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since Xen is an open source project, companies can create their own distributions. So basically OnApp XenServer and Citrix XenServer are based on the same underlying technology (Xen) and are generally compatible with other Xen distros. Because of that and as long as you have XenCenter access to the XenServer management IP, you should be able export the VMs from your current service provider and import them to your new one in order to preserve the identical environment from the Windows OS on up, more info in edocs here on exporting XenServer VMs to OVF: http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xencenter/6-5/xs-xc-vms-exportimport.html

Your process would be something like this:
1) Remove XenTools from the source VMs
2) Export VM to OVF/OVA format from source XenServer host
3) Copy exported OVF/OVA to new service provider (or keep local)
4) Connect to target XenServer host
5) Import OVF/OVA file as new VM
6) Configure/validate hardware settings for new VM on target XenServer host
7) Install XenTools from target XenServer host after confirming bootup on target XenServer

Some caveats to this being:
1) The IP configuration of each individual VM will be maintained when moved, so if using static IPs you will need to update once imported to the target XenServer host(s)
2) Any services provided by your current hosting provider (such as AD, SQL, DHCP, KMS) must be considered during planning and addressed appropriately
3) Depending on the licensing model in use in your current environment, you may not actually own the licenses in use and this must be determined/accounted for during planning
4) External configurations for networking are usually provided by your service provider and must be accounted for during planning and after importing the VMs to the target environment in order to ensure functionality for external connections.

There are other things to think about but that depends on the source and target environment and your specific configuration/topology and the apps/services you are hosting in this environment.

Comment: Good answer, just not sure if I have access to XenServer or if it is something I can install. I'm looking in to that

Comment: If you don't have access to the management interface of the XenServer host (which is pretty likely in a public cloud scenario), you would need to do a v2v but more like a p2v in that you would run a tool like XenConvert from within the source VM and eport in a format that would be compatible with the target environment, such as OVF. You can get XenConvert from here: https://www.citrix.com/downloads/xenserver/tools/conversion.html